# openapi send dynamic filename in response with file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi, api-gateway

I am sending a csv file in response of the API

```
  responses:
    200:
      description: "OK"
      headers: 
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
          $ref: "#/components/headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
      content:
        text/csv: 
          schema:
            type: string
```

I am using AWS services. It is returning the file but the filename which I am passing it from backend spring boot application, it is not returning the same.

When sending curl request with -O, it just creates the file with the name of the API last word. How can I send the file with the same filename from the application?

Comment: If you're using the "awsproxy" API Gateway integration you can specify the file name by setting the "Content-Disposition" header.

Comment: I already tried this, this is not working